# aurelia - error using material-components-web with skelton-esnext project

Tags: aurelia, material-components

I've successfully used the material-components-web library from within my aurelia skeleton-esnext-webpack projects but I am strugling to get them working in a skeleton-esnext project.

The problem seems to be with the fact that the skeleton-esnext project uses jspm with system.js as its module loader.

I have added `"@material/textfield": "npm:@material/textfield@^0.3.6"` to the jspm dependencies section of my package.json which seems to install the correct @material libraries to my jspm_modules/npm/@material.

Now, when I try to access any class from this library from within any my aurelia view models

```
import {MDCTextfieldFoundation} from '@material/textfield';
```

I get the following error in the browser when I run the project:

```
 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token import
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/@material/textfield@0.3.6.js:1:123)
        at eval (....
```

Any suggestions to whats most likely causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemJS is importing the raw source file of the plugin instead of the transpiled one (you can see this if you look into `jspm_packages/npm/@material/textfield@0.3.6.js`.

You can fix it by changing the location in there to point to the `dist` directory of the directory `textfield@0.3.6`. However, it gets overriden all the time on potential updates. And it is not saved in CVS.

Another, more simpler approach, would be to import the correct file in your view model:

```
import {MDCTextfieldFoundation} from '@material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield';
```

Comment: thanks marc scheib this fixes the error. one quick question we now reference @material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield but the actual folder/file in jspm_packages/npm is @material/textfield@0.3.6/dist/mdc.textfield i take it jspm knows to ignore the @0.3.6 part?